# QGIS 3.X CAD tools not working with snapping on PostgreSQL layers?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, snapping

If I create a scratch layer in EPSG 32720 CAD Tools are working fine with snapping options. The vertex are highlighted etc. etc.

If I use a PostgreSQL layer, same EPSG, the snaping is working, but not highlighted and angles are not recommended etc. etc.

Does anyone else have the same problem?